# Entity Framework worked weird when get parent information

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Currently, I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AM_Module](
    [ModuleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ModuleName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AM_ModuleID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ModuleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AM_Module]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AM_Module_AM_Module_ParentID] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AM_Module] ([ModuleID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AM_Module] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AM_Module_AM_Module_ParentID]
GO
```

With ParentID contains ModuleID's parent.

And I have 2 row like this:

```
ModuleID    ModuleName    ParentID
  1         ParentName       NULL
  2         ChildName         1
```

Now, in my EF, I run the LinQ to SQL:

```
        var q2 = from a in unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<AM_Module>().Queryable() where a.ParentID == 1 select a;
        var w2 = q2.ToList();
```

When I check by the SQL Profiler, I see the query will be parsed like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ModuleID] AS [ModuleID], 
    [Extent1].[ModuleName] AS [ModuleName], 
    [Extent1].[ParentID] AS [ParentID], 
    FROM [dbo].[AM_Module] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[ParentID]
```

The SQL returns 1 row.

But when I check w2[0].AM_Module1 (relationship with itself), I have value of parent with ModuleName too.

Why it happens? The SQL was returned only one row. How the EF know parent's data?

Please advise.

Comment: LINQ to SQL isn't use with EF, it will be LINQ to Entities: have you selected the wrong tag?

Comment: What is your definition of the entity types for EF? For a start model or code first? There are two potential association properties with the above definition (singular to the parent, collection to children): which you are using depends on the entity definition.

Comment: hi Richard, I was generated for EF by ReverseEngineerCodeFirst (Power Tool)

Comment: Could be lazy loading effect (is your `Parent` property `virtual`?). Or if the parent entity is already loaded in (tracked by) the `DbContext`.

Comment: Please include the .NET type `Module`in the question. And also what type is `unitOfWork`? (Likely we'll need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) re-create.)